# Implementing a distributed database system using Microsoft Excel (back-end) and JSP (front-end)

Tags: sockets, jsp, apache-poi, distributed-database

i am working on a project which is in short a distributed database project.

### **Requirements**

**module 1:**

1) Read and update an excel sheet using an excel sheet which already contains some data.

**status:** implemented.

Brief details:
i have used the POI from jakarta foundations as an API to interact with the excel sheets
using JSP.

**module 2:**

**status:** Help Needed.

Brief details:

1)this jsp page and the excel file is to be placed at various end users who can update their respective excel files. Now, on a time bound basis without them needing to upload this file to a server (intentionally) this file has to synchronize itself with the current corresponding entries present on the server .

2)Server has to work with following functions:

a.
Synchronization of previous data present on that server and the respective data (     present in the uploaded sheet) currently send.

b.
need to maintain checkpoints(in case of failures) and ensuring all the ACID properties of the database .

**Please please please!!!**
Help me Out regarding the technologies( and other api's if any) to properly implement the distributed nature of this database application.Thanks for your time.

Regards

Comment: can someone please help me out on this!! reaching the deadline!!